# Getting error while reading pdf : Can't read the embedded font IPGDLH+OpenSans

Tags: scala, pdfbox

When I am trying to convert pdf into images, I am getting this log :

```
Mar 12, 2014 1:49:49 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDCIDFontType2Font getawtFont
INFO: Can't read the embedded font IPGDLH+OpenSans
Mar 12, 2014 1:49:49 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType0Font getawtFont
INFO: Using font SansSerif.plain instead of IPGDLH+OpenSans
Mar 12, 2014 1:49:49 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDCIDFontType2Font getawtFont
INFO: Can't read the embedded font IPGDLH+OpenSans
Mar 12, 2014 1:49:49 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType0Font getawtFont
INFO: Using font SansSerif.plain instead of IPGDLH+OpenSans
Mar 12, 2014 1:49:49 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDCIDFontType2Font getawtFont
INFO: Can't read the embedded font IPGDLH+OpenSans
Mar 12, 2014 1:49:49 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType0Font getawtFont
INFO: Using font SansSerif.plain instead of IPGDLH+OpenSans
```

Due to this log, I am not getting proper conversion of pdf into images.

My code is:

```
val file = new File(path + name)

val doc = PDDocument.load(new FileInputStream(file));

val pages = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages()

val listOfImage= for (i <- 0 until pages.size()) yield {

                     val page = pages.get(i)

                     val image = page.asInstanceOf[PDPage].convertToImage()

                     image

                  }
```

and I am using these library :

```
"org.apache.pdfbox" % "pdfbox" % "1.8.2",


"org.apache.pdfbox" % "fontbox" % "1.8.2"
```

Please let me know if I am doing something wrong. Provide me some feasible solution for this.

Comment: Please share the PDF in question for inspection.